# Unable to recover the signed message in Solidity

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, sign

I am signing a message off-chain and trying to recover this via solidity(on-chain). Somehow, the signer address never matches.

**Off-chain code**

```
var message = 'Hello World';
var privateKey = '0xXXXXXXXX'; //Private key of the my using to sign message
var signatureMessage = web3.eth.accounts.sign(message, privateKey);
```

This gives me a signature value, however, when I am using the same signature and message on solidity to recover the singer's public address, I am getting a different address.

**Solidity**

```
function publicSaleBuy(bytes calldata signature, string memory message) external payable
    {
        if (!matchAddresSigner(hashTransaction(message), signature)){
            revert DirectMintFromNotAllowed();
        }else {
            _mint(1);
        }

    }

    function matchAddresSigner(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature)
        private
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        return signerAddress == hash.recover(signature);
    }

    function hashTransaction(string memory message) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(message));
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", messageHash));        
        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend you use a library for signature recovery. It saves gas costs and helps with debugging like this.

Comment: I would recommend using the ECDSA library to do this.  Very simple and uses less gas.